# Um Site como Background

Tags: css, background

Olá, é possível colocar um site da internet como backgroud usando css, como em background:url("file:///C:/logo.gif")?

Por exemplo background:url("file:///www.uol.com") ?

Answer (score 3):

Olá, como você deve especificar um arquivo para ser seu background acredito que um site não irá funcionar o que funcionaria seria você chamar o site dentro de um iframe. que é como um embed em seu site.

```html
<iframe src="https://www.uol.com.br" width="300" height="300">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

Comment: Estou tentando customizar a about:home do Firefox, mas parece só aceitar css, talvez por isso iframe não esteja funcionando.

Comment: por que você não cria um site e seta ele como pagina inicial?

Comment: Não é uma resposta, mas o site não localizou meu cadastro, então fiz outro com o mesmo nick. Seria uma boa opção, Gustavo, mas ainda não tenho conhecimento para criar um site com os mesmos elementos da about:home do Firefox (como botões de restaurar sessão, addons, downloads, etc) e depois inserir esse iframe com o Uol.com. Então, seria mais prático fazer o caminho inverso: usar um estilo em css para manipular a própria home do FF de modo que ela exiba o Uol.com em background sem que eu precise criar um outro site.

Comment: pelo nivel que voce está requisitando talvez um complemento ou extensão do proprio firefox seja o necessário. até a criação de um novo.